# groovy parse date MissingMethodException

Tags: java, date, parsing

Hello I`ve a problem with function parse

```
package demo
Date d1 = new Date()
d1.parse("yyyy.MM.dd","2016.02.10")
```

Or another combination:

```
d= new Date().parse('dd.MM.yyyy',"2016.02.10").format('yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Both throw an exception:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: 
No signature of method: static demo.Date.parse() 
is applicable for argument types: (
java.lang.String, java.lang.String) 
values: [yyyy.MM.dd, 2016.02.10]
```

Could someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 2):

Somehow you don't use `java.util.Date` but your own class `demo.Date` which of course does not have the `parse` method. Use `java.util.Date` instead and it will work.

Comment: haha yup :) that's why i led him to simpledateformat xD he can even format it now :)

Comment: well he doesn't want to parse it :D see his second one... he wants to format it in another format... :) he would have been confused if i had just given him Date

Comment: @Kushan I don't see what you mean. He can do it like in his second example if he uses the right class. `java.utill.Date` does have a `format` method in Groovy.

Comment: oh... had no idea about that.. Java doesn't have a format or a parse in Date so i assumed the same :)

Comment: @Kushan Groovy adds some helpful methods to standard Java classes: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html

Comment: Boy am i glad that they just decided to deprecate the whole damned Date and it's shenanigans in 1.8... simplified it insanely now :) any @Vampire thanks for the info.. that's cool :)